# django template url from js file

Tags: jquery, django, datatables, django-templates

In django project I have `urls.py` like `url(r'^data/$', get_data, name='data'),`

I can add in my template `data.html` like `<a href='{% url 'data' %}'>Create New Data</a>` and it works fine. When I click on link, it displays `localhost://data`.

Now I am displaying a table dynamically, using jquery and datatable in `data.js`, and I am able to make clickable table cell using the following code:

```
$('#table').DataTable( {
     "columnDefs": [
            {
                "render": function (data, type, row){
                    return "<a href='blawblawblaw'>Click cell</a>";
             },
             ]
})
```

Can I pass url through above return statement? something like

`return "<a href='{% url 'data' %}'>Click cell</a>";`

If I try with above I get error 404 error with `The current URL, {% url, didn't match any of these.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the syntax like: `'{% url 'data' %}'` is for django template, Django will render HTML on server side, then response the rendered HTML to client.

When we call `render(request, template)` in `views.py`, Django will fill in the content written in template like: `{% url 'data' %}`.

If your url is same for each data object, you can paste your js code in template, using Django to render the content.

If your url is dynamic change for each data object, I would give the data object additional information field like: `"url"` or `"id"`, So that the client can get the correct URL path.

Syntax like: `{% .... %}` in Django is for server side, Not for client side. You can open developer tool, take a look at the return value, and your will see the original string: `"<a href='blawblawblaw'>Click cell</a>"`

Comment: `{% block content %}

<table id="table" class="table table-striped">

{% endblock content %}` This is my current `data.html` and table gets rendered dynamically from `data.js`  so I am not sure how to add `{% url 'data' %}` in `data.html` for table cell?

Comment: for first one do you mean just copy `data.js` in `data.html`? for second one can you please give example.

Comment: If the URL is const in your urls, you can paste your js body in template, using Django render function to render your data.

If the URL is different from each data object in js, you should add some url information in data object and retrieve those information in js.